# How can I update child objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongojs

I want to store objects like this with mongodb:

```
{    
    field: 'example',  
    attr: {
        tmp : 'test',
        tmp1 : 'test1'
    }
};
```

Now I would like to search for the entry which has the property `field:'example'` and add a field to its `attr` object. How can I do this in mongojs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `tmp2:'test2'` value into the collection as follows.

```
db.myObject.update({field:'example'},{$set:{'attr.tmp2':'test2'}})
```

Comment: db.myObject.update({field:'example'},{$set:{'attr.tmp2':'test2'}, {upsert: true}}) <-- if tmp2 is not present in the current document.